# User activity logging application

Tags: c#

How do i start if i wanted to log in a database the user activity (i.e. Open internet explorer (maybe even the website?), open Visual Studio). Is there a .Net class i should be looking at using? Thanks.(C#)

Answer (score 1):

.net doesn't have any helper classes to do this directly.

To be honest, you may need to go down to C++ to catch a lot of things, perhaps using the antivirus API's to watch process invokations and you will have to insert a plugin into ie to monitor it effectively.